# Accessing model properties unit testing

Tags: unit-testing

I am getting model in my unit test like

```
// Arrange
var c = new MyController();

//Act
var result = c.Index(null,null);
var model = result.ViewData.Model;
```

But that model is having values e.g. ActionName

How to access that value?

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewData.Model` is of type `object`. You need to cast it to the correct type like this:

```
MyModel model = ViewData.Model as MyModel;
// access model.SomeProperty
```